# How to create random numbers with zero padding in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a question. I am creating simple form using jquery and I have a textbox that can generate code. And my format is like this.

```
XXXX - 0###-0###

XXXX - means first 4 character of name
0### - means 0001 - 1000
```

How can I generate that?

```
<tr>
    <td><span class="required">*</span><?php echo $entry_supplier_code; ?></td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="supplier_code" id="supplier_code" value="" size="50" readonly="readonly" />
        <?php if($error_supplier_code) { ?>
            <span class="error"><?php echo $error_supplier_code; ?></span>
        <?php } ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><span class="required">*</span><?php echo $entry_supplier_name; ?></td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="supplier_name" id="supplier_name" value="" size="50" />
    <?php if ($error_supplier_name) { ?>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $error_supplier_name; ?></span>
    <?php } ?>
  </td>
    </td>
</tr>

....

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#tabs a').tabs(); 
    $('#vtab-option a').tabs();

    $('#supplier_name').keydown(function(){

        var supplier_name = $('#supplier_name').val();
        var trim_name = (supplier_name.substring(0,4)).toUpperCase();

        var first_random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
        var second_random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);

        var generate_code = trim_name + ' - ' + first_random + ' - ' + second_random;

        $('#supplier_code').val(generate_code);

    });

</script>
```

That's all guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((generate_code)+10000).toString().substring(1)
```